# How can I produce a mosaic chart / Marimekko chart?

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to make a stacked ybar plot with three stacked components on each bar, with each component divided vertically into three percentage components (the total width of these components stay the same: 100%). One bar of the plot could be described by the following matrix:

> 23 30% 50% 20%
>
> 55 10% 40% 50%
>
> 32 60% 30% 10%

meaning that the first (base) part of the bar would have a hight of 32, and be devided into three parts vertically with relative widths 60:30:10 (so three narrow lines with different widths standing next to each other and touching). The second (middle part) would have a hight of 55, added on top of the 32-high first bar, and be divided into three parts with relative widths 10:40:50. The third (top) part would have a height of 23, divided into three parts with relative widths 30:50:20.

(The input format is not important, and flipping around the numbers or dividing the matrix into two or more does not matter---the important part is getting plot as described.)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

edit: Clarification:

The above example and table describes only one of the bars.

Another way to describe it would be to make a ybar plot, where each ybar is a mosaic chart or a Marimekko chart, so that each bar contains the kind of chart that is presented below in the answer by Jake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This chart type is called a *mosaic chart* or a *Marimekko chart*. There's an insightful critique of this type of chart over at [Junk Charts](http://junkcharts.typepad.com/junk_charts/2011/03/the-best-way-to-handle-two-dimensions-may-be-to-not-use-two-dimensions.html) that points out some of the shortcomings one has to be aware of.

Nonetheless, they can be created in PGFPlots relatively easily, in your case by combining `xbar interval` with `stack dir=x`. `xbar interval` allows the creation of horizontal bars with different thicknesses according to the `y` value. In order for this to work, you need to add a dummy data row to your table, and you need to accumulate the `y` values, otherwise the bars would overlap. You can do that with a `create on use` expression using `pgfplotstable`. The `xbar interval` needs to be supplied to the individual plots, not the axis, since otherwise the different parts of the bars would be offset relatively to each other.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
23 30 50 20
55 10 40 50
32 60 30 10
0 0 0 0
}\datatable

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/accumy/.style={
        create col/expr={\prevrow{0}+\pgfmathaccuma}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    stack plots=x,
    enlargelimits=false,
    table/y=accumy]
\addplot [fill=orange!60,xbar interval] table [x index=1] {\datatable};
\addplot [fill=cyan!50,xbar interval] table [x index=2] {\datatable};
\addplot [fill=yellow!50,xbar interval] table [x index=3] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

To create a chart consisting of several such charts, I believe your best bet is to use individual `axis` environments positioned relatively to each other. It's not possible to have several independent `stack` plots in one `axis` environment.

In my opinion, the result is quite pretty to look at, but not very useful for communicating data `=)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
23 30 50 20
55 10 40 50
32 60 30 10
0 0 0 0
}\datatableA

\pgfplotstableread{
11 10 50 40
20 30 20 50
60 30 50 20
0 0 0 0
}\datatableB

\pgfplotstableread{
33 30 50 20
55 10 40 50
32 60 30 10
0 0 0 0
}\datatableC

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/accumy/.style={
        create col/expr={\prevrow{0}+\pgfmathaccuma}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=3cm, y=0.03cm,
    name=main axis,
    hide x axis,
    stack plots=x,
    enlargelimits=false,
    table/y=accumy]
\addplot [fill=orange!60,xbar interval] table [x index=1] {\datatableA};
\addplot [fill=cyan!50,xbar interval] table [x index=2] {\datatableA};
\addplot [fill=yellow!50,xbar interval] table [x index=3] {\datatableA};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    name=second axis,
    at=(main axis.south east), anchor=south west, xshift=1ex,
    width=3cm, y=0.03cm, hide axis,
    stack plots=x,
    enlargelimits=false,
    table/y=accumy]
\addplot [fill=orange!60,xbar interval] table [x index=1] {\datatableB};
\addplot [fill=cyan!50,xbar interval] table [x index=2] {\datatableB};
\addplot [fill=yellow!50,xbar interval] table [x index=3] {\datatableB};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    at=(second axis.south east), anchor=south west, xshift=1ex,
    width=3cm, y=0.03cm, hide axis,
    stack plots=x,
    enlargelimits=false,
    table/y=accumy]
\addplot [fill=orange!60,xbar interval] table [x index=1] {\datatableC};
\addplot [fill=cyan!50,xbar interval] table [x index=2] {\datatableC};
\addplot [fill=yellow!50,xbar interval] table [x index=3] {\datatableC};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate your informative answer, as well as the caution not to make charts to complicated (or ugly ;)). I realize that I did not state my question in the clearest way---the plot that you described in your answer should be just one of the bars in the plot I want. In other words, take the plot in the answer, squeeze it from the sides so that it becomes tall and narrow, and then add more such bars. I realize that there is a substantial risk that it may be to cramped to be useful, but I would still like to try it out if it is possible.

Comment: @hjb981: Wow, hehe, that's going to be messy. I've edited my answer to show one possible way of doing that.

Comment: Wow, impressively fast! I just drew a picture of the above and went to the scanner, and when I was back to my computer to upload it, there was your answer. And yes, I agree, it may be way to messy, but I still really appreciate your answer so that I now have the option of trying, to see what it will look like.

Comment: Marimekko chart? Seriously? `:-D`

Comment: @Jake If you try the examples with `pgfplots` version 1.10 or 1.11, the output is different (and wrong).

Comment: @Jake please see egreg's comment above. The same happens in v1.12. Any ideas?