# Mosaic/Marimekko charts; does this answer still work?

Tags: pgfplots

I found this answer [How can I produce a mosaic chart / Marimekko chart?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62774/how-can-i-produce-a-mosaic-chart-marimekko-chart)
and have used it before to create beautiful charts.

Under Texlive-2014, 
with pgfplots version 1.10,
I receive a lot of white spaces in the examples on the previous mentioned url.
Using the mwe from the mentioned answer

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
23 30 50 20
55 10 40 50
32 60 30 10
0 0 0 0
}\datatable

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/accumy/.style={
        create col/expr={\prevrow{0}+\pgfmathaccuma}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    stack plots=x,
    enlargelimits=false,
    table/y=accumy]
\addplot [fill=orange!60,xbar interval] table [x index=1] {\datatable};
\addplot [fill=cyan!50,xbar interval] table [x index=2] {\datatable};
\addplot [fill=yellow!50,xbar interval] table [x index=3] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the resulting picture can be retrieved in this link, and it is not the intended, nor the original result.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwAsCc3wS5VbDNyYkZjSVVYdUU/view?usp=sharing

Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! There are several code snippets in the question you link, it still would be useful if you could present a MWE (minimal working example) showing exactly what code you are compiling. You should also include a screenshot to illustrate the unwanted behavior. You don't have enough reputation to include images yet, but if you just upload the image anywhere and include a link, somebody will be glad to help you and add the relevant image balises.

Comment: I can confirm the problem: it happened somewhere between versions 1.8 and 1.10 of `pgfplots`. I left a comment to Jake's answer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.