# Plotting: Regression Tree and Partitions

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-qtree

I am trying to reconstruct the following two graphs in Latex but have not succeeded yet. Altough I heard about the following two packages:

> \usepackage{tikz}
>   \usepackage{tikz-qtree}

I am not able to reconstruct them. Does anyone of you have any advice?

Thank you for your help.

[image: Partition and Regression Tree]

Comment: please accept the answer and upvote if you feel it has helped you -- the green tick mark on the left of the answer and the up pointing triangle

Comment: you may find this useful in your learning of recursive binary splitting --- 
 https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/HumanitiesScience/StatLearning/asset/trees.pdf

Comment: https://www.ke.tu-darmstadt.de/lehre/archiv/ws0809/mldm/dt.pdf

Comment: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/12/detailed-solutions-for-skilltest-tree-based-algorithms/

Comment: Thank you for the useful links and your help. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

One part of your requirement straight from the book-- http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-qtree/tikz-qtree-manual.pdf

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
-- +(0,-8pt)
-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\Tree [.S [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[.PP [.P on ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT1

Node names can be moved by adding options such as `[\edge node[xshift=20pt,yshift=5pt]{$y$};`

Here `y` and `pp` have been shifted

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt) -| (\tikzchildnode)}}}

\Tree [\edge node[xshift=20pt,yshift=5pt]{$y$}; [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[\edge node[xshift=30pt,yshift=5pt]{$pp$};  [.P on ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

### EDIT2

The first part of the requirement has been answered below -- a little adaptation will be required -- this is from the this same site answer on Jan 23, 2019 -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525323/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
    % use `compat' level 1.11 or higher so coordinates don't have to be
    % prefixed with `axis cs:' (any more)
    compat=1.11,
    }
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    region/.style={
        draw=black!50,
        dashed,
    },
    Node/.style={
        midway,
        red,
    },
    declare function={
        xmin=0;
        xmax=12;
        ymin=0;
        ymax=300;
    },
    ]
    \begin{axis}[hide axis,
        xlabel={},
        ylabel={},
        xmin=xmin,
        xmax=xmax,
        ymin=ymin,
        ymax=ymax,
        axis background/.style={},
        extra x ticks={},
        extra y ticks={},
        title=title,
        ]
                    \draw [region,fill=brown!40] (xmin,ymin) rectangle (8,ymax)  node [Node, xshift=-55, yshift=-76] {68\%};

        \draw [region,fill=blue!40] (8,ymin)  rectangle (10,50)  node [Node, xshift=-10, yshift=-9] {5\%};
        \draw [region,fill=red!40] (10,ymin)   rectangle (xmax,50)  node [Node, xshift=-10, yshift=-9] {5\%};
        \draw [region,fill=gray!40] (8,50)   rectangle (xmax,ymax) node [Node, xshift=-24, yshift=-64] {22\%};

        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

After adaptation of the same code the OP can get the following ---

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The problem of how to create the tree is hence solved. Do you have any idea how to create the coresponding graph on the left?

Comment: yaa sure added above

Comment: Thank you for the help